# Objective C compare UIButton if(sender==button)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Hey I am trying to get the button in the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` listener. I used to do that with tags but I got sick of this now as I can do all that in Android simply by doing something like `arg0==button`.

I set the selector like that

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(actionUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in this method

```
- (IBAction)actionUp:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;

    if(b==button){
        NSLog(@"yeeeee");
    }
}
```

nothing happens, the two objects `b` and `button` are almost the same but refer to another address in memory (like with 2 strings compared with ==).

`b` definitely gets the button right as I can do

```
[b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Which addresses the button right.

So what can I do?

EDIT: pasted the wrong methods, sorry for that (error still persists tho, I just renamed them quickly for the post)

EDIT SOLVED: isEqual: worked for me. What's weird is that after rebooting even == worked again. I cleaned the project before but that didn't help, but restarting my Mac did 0o Thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with tags? You can simply use sender.tag value

Comment: you shouldnt compare memory address for two buttons, they are always different.

Comment: I have all the buttons in a huge array and I just don't want to name them all. I could use the array index for the tag but it's just not the same :< I am not comparing memory addresses I just explained what happens if you do

Comment: how many buttons do you have ?

Comment: `actionUp:` and `actionPick:`? Are you looking at the good method?

Comment: @Mr.T It's fine and normal to compare buttons like this using `==`.

Comment: 42 on the main view + 50 on another view + 2*10 on other views

Comment: @Larme I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You are using `@selector(actionUp:)` and the method you post is `- (IBAction)actionPick:(id)sender`. Clearly not the same method. Plus, how do you get `button` var in the method?

Comment: Just realized it, edited, thanks for that. (made a mistake pasting the code). The `button` is declared in the .h file

Comment: @Mr.T Comparing `sender` with the value stored inside an outlet is the preferred way to do this. Another solution is to have separate `IBAction` handler for every button. Tags should be used only in very special circumstances, they always introduce magic numbers to code and that's an antipattern.

Comment: I never dealt with having buttons in an array and load stuff. I always prefer to use outlets for buttons. Its good to know ,Thanks for the info!!!

Comment: There's something wrong in code you're not showing. `==` in that case compares identities (via pointer values). The `sender` is the `UIControl` on which the action happened. Therefore if your comparison fails then you're not comparing to the same button. Prove it to yourself by doing something like `b.frame = <something crazy>` within the action. The button you pressed will adopt some crazy frame.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", button)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
if ([sender isEqual:button]) {
    NSLog(@"yeeeee");
    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;

    [b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't work any better than using `==` because `UIButton` and its class hierarchy don't implement `isEqual:` so the default will be to simply compare pointers, like `==`.

Comment: I believe that you should test this implementation because it works

Comment: @RubensIotti I know it works. I'm saying that if `isEqual:` works than so should `==`. And the OP comments in an update to their question that `==` is now working for them.

Comment: Right @rmaddy, I understood your position. Really "==" should it woks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better with

```
   if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
...
```

Comment: this answer seems off topic to the original question. I realize that adding this would make the code safer, but that's not what he was asking.